# Scala version of Jgit

Tags: scala, jgit

Looking for a stable Scala implementation (or something similar) of JGit.

Has anyone worked with anything like it?

I've found scala-git but it's not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did the same search some time ago, but I concluded that it was preferable to use JGit (even if it's a Java library) in Scala. It's used by products with lots of users (eclipse, netbeans, gerrit,...) and even some Scala products like [Gitbucket](https://github.com/takezoe/gitbucket) use it.
Its API can be easily called from Scala, and does not result in ugly code, nor needs heavy wrappers.
Personally I prefer using a Java lib widely used than a pure Scala lib for which I don't know the roadmap nor if it's still maintained. I thought to [ScalaGit](https://github.com/kaisellgren/ScalaGit) but it seemed really young (only 67 commits) and not actively maintained (last commit on Apr 21, 2014).

Answer (score 2):

Any java library (like jgit) is perfectly usable in scala as scala run in the java runtime environment. Is there any reason why you can't use it?

Comment: of course I can use it. I was looking for a scal library that has a more scala-ish API